# Why is a sinner king not punished for his karma by Yama just because he is a devotee of Shiva in Skanda Purana?

Tags: puranas, shaivism

So I was reading Skanda purana and there is a part about a sinner king( who later became Canda) who did all sorts of bad things like murder etc but was not punished by Yama just because he is a devotee of Shiva and was even granted entry to Kailasa. Ravana was also a devotee and he suffered and paid for his karma. Isn't this unfair? What are your thoughts? And please don't say that this is symbolic story to represent the authority of Shiva and power of his name.

Om Namah Shivaay

Comment: Ravana was never a 'devotee'

Comment: Was he completely forgiven for his sin forever ? Or only for the time being ? A person can be saved from his sin only for some time, not forever.

Comment: @Shiva_Mahesvara this isn't Ravana. This particular story has a character who was like Ravana but died peacefully and after dying became permanent Shiv gana

Comment: @Shiva_Mahesvara please explain this https://hindi.webdunia.com/aarti-chalisa/shiv-tandav-stotram-114100100059_1.html

Comment: @Hope That has no scriptural basis. No scripture says ravana to be the composer of that stotra